# how to wrap dynamic button in stackpanel programmatically? [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, button, stackpanel

I would like to add 16 button in the form of 4 rows and 4 columns programmatically in a stack panel. When I add my buttons in stack panel I can view only 4 button in it. I am unable to wrap it. I don't want to use wrap panel to resolve the issue.(Wrap panel cause issue when window maximize).

Here is my code,

```
 foreach (var buttonName in list)
 {
   Button newButton = new Button(){Content = "button_name"};
   this.mainPanel.Children.Add(newButton);
 }
```

XML,

```
<StackPanel x:Name="mainPanel" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
```

Comment: use grid instead. if you need both horizontal and vertical management. you said rows and columns. grid is your solution

Comment: Thanks @M.kazemAkhgary for suggesting grid as solution. I have resolved it and posted my answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all you need :

```
 UniformGrid g = new UniformGrid(){ Rows = 4, Columns = 4};
        g.Children.Add(new Button());
        ... add your 16 buttons ...
```

UniformGrid knows how to present its content as (Rows x Columns).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have done it.   Thank you M.kazem Akhgary for suggesting grid as solution.

```
GridLengthConverter gridLengthConverter = new GridLengthConverter();
            RowDefinition row1 = new RowDefinition();
            row1.Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
            RowDefinition row2 = new RowDefinition();
            row2.Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
            RowDefinition row3 = new RowDefinition();
            row3.Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
            RowDefinition row4 = new RowDefinition();
            row4.Height = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");

            mainPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(row1);
            mainPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(row2);
            mainPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(row3);
            mainPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(row4);
            ColumnDefinition col1 = new ColumnDefinition();
            col1.Width = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
            ColumnDefinition col2 = new ColumnDefinition();
            col2.Width = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
            ColumnDefinition col3 = new ColumnDefinition();
            col3.Width = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");
            ColumnDefinition col4 = new ColumnDefinition();
            col4.Width = (GridLength)gridLengthConverter.ConvertFrom("*");

            mainPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col1);
            mainPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col2);
            mainPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col3);
            mainPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(col4);
            int row = 0;
            int col = 0;
            foreach (var buttonName in List)
            {
                if(row<=4)
                {
                    if (col <= 4)
                    {
                        Button newButton = new Button()
                        {
                            Content = buttonName.Name,

                        };
                        Grid.SetRow(newButton, row);
                        Grid.SetColumn(newButton, col);
                        col++;
                        this.mainPanel.Children.Add(newButton);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row++;
                        col = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
```